# Rolling Windows function for count distinct customer state

Tags: sql, rolling-computation, snowflake-schema

I am trying to count distinct customer status in the last 3 months, 6 months.

I have `customer_id`, `customer_status` (active or not), and `calendar_date`. Each customer can hence appear multiple times over time as it can be active or not, on different times.

but when I try the code below it doesn't work as count(distinct) is not supported with the windows function

```
select *,
count(distinct customer_status)
    over(partition by customer_id
        order by date_trunc ('month',calendar_date) rows between 2 PRECEDING and current row)

from customer_details
```

I can get the distinct state in the same month [see below] but I wanted to create two fields for count(distinct) 3 months and six months.

```
select calendar_date,
           date_trunc ('month',calendar_date) as calendar_month,
           customer_id,
           customer_status,
    
    count(distinct customer_status)
        over(partition by customer_id, calendar_month))
    
    from customer_details
    order by calendar_date
```

Can someone please support me?

The final select should have following columns:

```
calendar_date [already exist]
calendar_month [already exist]
customer_status [already exist]
count_distinct_status_3month [new]
count_distinct_status_6months [new]
```

I would like to do this using windows function

Comment: Snowflake doesn't really support `count(distinct)` as a window function.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with window functions.  You can do this using a lateral join:

```
select cd.*, cd2.*
from customer_details cd cross join lateral
     (select count(distinct cd2.customer_status) as cnt1,
             count(distinct case when cd2.calendar_date > cd.calendar_date - interval '3 month' then cd2.customer_status end) as cnt2,
             count(distinct case when cd2.calendar_date > cd.calendar_date - interval '6 month' then cd2.customer_status end) as cnt3
      from customer_details cd2
      where cd2.customer_id = cd.customer_id
     ) cd2
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a no direct function to this, but rather need to use self joins. For example in your case, the query would be something like this.

```
select cust.calendar_date, date_trunc('month', cust.calendar_date) as calendar_month,
cust.customer_id, count(distinct cust_3mon.customer_status) as count_distinct_status_3month,
count(distinct cust_6mon.customer_status) as count_distinct_status_6month
from customer_details as cust
left join customer_details as cust_3mon
on cust.customer_id=cust_3mon.customer_id
and (date_trunc('month', cust.calendar_date)-date_trunc('month', cust_3mon.calendar_date)) between interval '0 months' and interval '3 months'
left join customer_details as cust_6mon
on cust.customer_id=cust_6mon.customer_id
and (date_trunc('month', cust.calendar_date)-date_trunc('month', cust_6mon.calendar_date)) between interval '0 months' and interval '6 months'
group by 1,2,3
order by 3,2
```

sqlfiddle link [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/69c910/1)